# Losing a non-native accent of English

Tags: english, accent

I realize this question has been done to death in other contexts, but I have already exhausted the possibilities covered in similar threads all across the web. I am a fluent (I hold the Certificate of Proficiency in English from Cambridge University) non-native speaker of English. I have no problems expressing myself either in writing or speaking, save for one aspect - my accent. I have already done several accent-reduction courses in addition to persistently practicing shadowing. As a result, my accent did improve considerably, but native speakers I converse with still take me for a foreigner 95% of the time. Are there any other techniques I could try to finally acquire that crisp, neutral accent or am I doomed to answering the tedious question of where am I from forever? Any hints would be welcome.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic.   Speech therapy for accent change really isn't part of linguistics.

Comment: I"m curious, what 'crisp neutral accent' are you talking about?

Comment: If this kind of question is off-topic here, then the [language learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning) proposal would be the perfect place for this kind of question - please support the proposal if you want a better place to ask these kinds of questions.

Comment: Some linguists consider Received Pronunciation (the Queen's English) the unaccented variety of English. Is that the type of English you want?

Comment: 1. Even RP is not a monolith but rather a group of accents. 2. RP is considered posh and too pretentious, so those speakers who have some kind of RP accent try to avoid using it.

Comment: @AlexB. True. In fact, any kind of accented English non-native to a certain environment, especially in countries where English is a second language, is considered pretentious. I have a mild southern British accent and I often get condescending remarks, even by actual linguists from my country (Malaysia).

Answer (score 3):

You've been offered a part playing an Australian stevedore, but you have to pick up the accent in just two weeks.  It's only a few lines you have to get right.  Concentrate on the sounds and the rhythm -- forget what the lines mean.  After that, maybe there's an drunken Italian pastry chef role for you.

That is to say, it's not a matter of getting rid of your old accent, but learning new ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think before making the assumption that you need to completely lose your foreign accent, there are a couple things to consider.

You say you're able to express yourself freely in both speaking and writing, and at least your one post gives some evidence of this.  There's one other important thing - that people can comprehend you.  If your accent isn't strong enough to impede communication, then it isn't something you truly have to worry about.  If people do have trouble understanding you, then you will want to identify what aspects of your pronunciation are hard to follow, and work on those aspects.  Over time, you'll learn how to make people understand, even if you're accent remains.

Second, you need to decide whether you really want a native-sounding accent.  Many people choose to maintain a little bit of their accent when they learn English, in order to maintain their identity.  That is your choice to make, not anyone else's.  If you want to sound American or British, make the effort.  But if you'd like to maintain a little accent, then do that.

If you want to erase all traces of your accent, you have to first accept that it may not be possible.  According to the [Critical period hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_period_hypothesis), "perfect" language acquisition is very difficult past the teenage years, and accent is an area that has proven very difficult to change past the critical period.  You didn't give your age, but if you're an adult, it will be much harder.

If you're determined to have an accent that doesn't sound foreign, it may be best to consider what kind of accent you do want.  There isn't really a "neutral accent", and you may have more success if you're aiming for a particular accent, whether it be English, Australian, Southern U.S., or whatever.  Beyond that, keep monitoring your accent, so your pronunciation is less likely to fossilize. Try doing things that force you to enunciate more exactly, like singing or acting. And if you can identify the aspects of your accent that are most obvious, you can focus on changing those aspects first.